# Нахождение остовного дерева наименьшего веса. Алгоритм Крускала

Tags: алгоритм, c++

В гугле находил этот алгоритм, но никак не могу понять как это реализовывать! Помогите, пожалуйста. В программе нужно реализовать ввод начальных параметров, чтобы найти остовное дерево наименьшего веса.

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм Крускала - не самый тривиальный для реализации.

Если следовать классическому алгоритму, описанному в *Кормене*, то вам необходимо запрограммировать следующие вещи *(в случае, если все реализовывается самостоятельно):*

- Структуру данных для хранения графа (я бы использовал список смежности), чтение графа из файла, из `std::cin` или еще каким-либо способом.
- Структуру данных, эмулирующую систему **непересекающихся множеств**, используемую в алгоритме
- Собственно **сам алгоритм** (псевдокод которого, опять же, лучше посмотреть в *Кормене*).

Comment: А как сама программа должна работать? Какие действия выполнять и тд?

Comment: @hasded Ну в простом случае - считать граф, построить `MST` и вывести список его ребер на экран. В сложном случае - полностью визуализировать алгоритм.

Comment: а я вот нашел одну программу, там нужно вводить вот это:
1)Максимально допустимое значение веса ребра
2)Ввести число вершин
3)Ввести нижний треугольник матрицы стоимости
и после ввода, выдается "Матрица достижимости отсортированное по убыванию", "Вывод ребер максимального веса" и "Стоимость дерева"
так и должно быть в моем случае?

Comment: @hasded Вы пытаетесь научиться или хотите **просто сдать?** Если второе - то вам на [**www.kursovik.com**][1]

[1]: http://www.kursovik.com

Comment: я пытаюсь и научиться и потом сдать))) просто у меня должен быть пример как все это делать...

Answer (score 2):

Сам алгоритм, для будущих поколений ) [Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)

1. минимальное остовное дерево T сначала пустое
2. сортируем ребра исходного графа G по возрастанию цены ребра
3. для каждого ребра выполняем следующий шаг:
4. если ребро не образует цикл в T - то добавляем его в T
5. в итоге получаем минимальное оставное дерево

Главное здесь - шаг 3 (**если ребро не образует цикл**) Для проверки образуется цикл или нет можно, например, использовать структуру [UnionFind](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2) для хранения списка используемых вершин

Т.е. в шаге 3 мы, кроме добавления ребра в T, так же добавляем вершины в список используемых вершин. Тогда проверка - образуется ли цикл или нет сводится к проверке двух вершин ребра на вхождение в набор использованных вершин. Если хотя бы одна вершина в нашем списке отсутствует - тогда при добавлении данного ребра цикл не образуется.

Вместо UnionFind можно использовать и [Хэш-таблицы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0). Логика та же. Главное - использовать структуру, которая позволяет за O(1) проверить содержится ли элемент в наборе или нет.